# I am getting three attributes instead of one. ExtractText Processor NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

So I am trying to extract attributes from file with the line format NUMBER/TEXT, for example like this:

> 9999, text

I am creating attribute **number** with the regular expression like this **(\d{4})**

But instead of one attribute number, I am getting 3 attributes number, number0 and number1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression `\d{4}` without brackets. It returns only one attribute `number.0`

Comment: Hi! Thank you! But can you please explain why is this happening anyways??